# What does Dumbledore see in the Mirror of Erised?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

We know from the first book that Dumbledore guessed what Harry must be seeing in the Mirror of Erised (his family, assuming Dumbledore cannot directly see the Mirror anyway - which could be a possibility since he could alter it).

In the chapter in which this happens, JKR doesn't immediately reveal what Dumbledore sees when he looks in the Mirror.

Is it later revealed by JKR what Dumbledore sees when he looks in the Mirror of Erised?

Comment: [Here's what he saw in the mirror.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wu4KrQcy23A) starts at 2:50 in. Btw, I drew the artwork and arranged the music. :)

Comment: Same thing as Harry. Feel like this is a dupe...

Comment: @DavidS I searched, but didn't find this question.

Comment: Doesn't he say he saw himself with wooly socks?

Comment: @RedCaio Favorited. EXCELLENT artwork man! I've never seen more lifelike pencil drawings before.

Comment: Neil Patrick Harris.

Comment: @DavidS It probably feels like a dupe because Rowling answered this years ago, which is probably also why it isn't a dupe. Strange world.

Comment: No images of Dumbledore wearing 'socks' please. You're not the only one, and you WILL get reported.

Comment: @RedCaio Seconded: amazing artwork there! :-)

Comment: @DavidS Possible duplicate of [What is Dumbledore's fascination with socks?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/what-is-dumbledores-fascination-with-socks?lq=1), since the accepted answer there also resolves this question.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Titles are different - both may not show up in a given search result. Questions should be merged, if something like that is possible.

Comment: @cst1992 Dupe-closing is different from other kinds of closing, and duplicates still show up in search results and help increase searchability. And yes, merging is possible, but that puts all the answers into a single thread, so it should only be done when the answer(s) to one question also work perfectly well as answer(s) to the other. Not sure if this is the case here, but I'll think about it.

Comment: Time to reopen after The Crimes of Grindelwald - one question is clearly not a dupe of another, considering at one point Dumbledore did not see socks nor Ariana.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Dumbledore sees the same thing as Harry - his family, alive and well. Harry realises this in Deathly Hallows.

> Harry did not ask whether Dumbledore had ever found out who struck
>   Ariana dead. He did not want to know, and even less did he want
>   Dumbledore to have to tell him. At last he knew what Dumbledore would
>   have seen when he looked in the mirror of Erised, and why Dumbledore
>   had been so understanding of the fascination it had exercised over
>   Harry.

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71427/what-is-dumbledores-fascination-with-socks) has a quote from JK confirming this:

> **Allie:** What did dumbledore truly see in the mirror of Erised?
>   **J.K. Rowling:** He saw his family alive, whole and happy – Ariana, Percival and Kendra all returned to him, and Aberforth reconciled to him. (source: [J.K. Rowling Web Chat Transcript Jul 30, 2007](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript/))

Answer (score 0):

As depicted in *Fantastic Beasts 2*, in his earlier years Dumbledore saw his lover, Grindlewald in the mirror.